# Man using a woman's siddur

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

If a guy were to daven using the Artscroll women's siddur, would that be considered a violation of the prohibition of *beged isha*?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Why so many downvotes on this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prohibition is actually of a man wearing שמלת אש"ה - small's A.S.H., which stands for ArtScroll Sefard Hebrew. Thus, only the pocket-sized Sefard ones are prohibited, so most of [these](http://www.artscroll.com/Items.aspx?hierId=P11) are fine.